# router.navigate(url) not going through Service worker fetch event

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker

Our platform is old angular (v4) and we use plain JavaScript file (sw.js) to register Service worker in index html page. I see install and activate are working fine. Just simple events [for testing]

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting()); // Activate worker immediately
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()); // Become available to all pages
});
```

Then Angular component routes to our main page via router.navigate('pagename')
and browser even routes to that page,  but service worker fetch event is not triggered..

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(onFetch(event)));
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Is your route lazy loaded? If not it will definitely not be loaded via HTTP, but rather be embalmed in page

Comment: No. it is not lazy loading. Just route to the component via 
router.navigate(componentname).. . But I really need to intercept and go this request through service worker fetch event. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: Problem is it [router.navigate(componentname)] does not hit this fetch event at all...